# In IE using Parsely validation on focus I'm getting two icons

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, parsley

I'm using parsley validation. When I open focus on input field, it shows two icons one is parsley validation but other only display in IE. Anybody can help me?

Comment: Would you be able to provide the script?

Comment: <input name="email" class="form-control parsley-success" id="subs_email" type="email" placeholder="Enter email address" value="" data-parsley-error-message="Please enter a valid email address" data-parsley-trigger="change keypress keyup focusout" data-parsley-required="True" data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-errors-container="#parsleyerrorsubscribeemail" data-parsley-id="39">